# I want to customise my yii URL

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

This is my URL:

`http://localhost/techsupportscam/index.php/question/search/2?category=XP+Support`

Now I want to convert into something like this:

`http://localhost/techsupportscam/index.php/question/search/2/XP+Support`

My Controller is `question` and method is `search`.

My link is:

`<?php echo  Yii::app()->createUrl('question/search/',array('id'=>$subCategory->id,'category'=>$subCategory->title)); ?>">`

How I can do this? Can you guys please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Rewrite the url manager in `config/main.php`. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503041/email-verification-in-yii-framework?rq=1

Comment: I have already un comment my url manager code in config.php

Comment: in you case rule may be like 
`<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<id1:\d+>//<id2:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>/<id1>/<id2>`
Just check on. and use `.htaccess`if you dont get it.

Comment: I usually do like `<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('question/search/'.$subCategory->id.'/'.$subCategory->title); ?>">`. But I think it is not the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this as this on CUrlManager rules,

```
'rules' => array(
                'question/search/<id:\d+>/<category>/*' => 'question/search',

                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

Comment: why you have used '.*?>' ?

Comment: you can do it like 'question/search/<id:\d+>/<category>/*' also !

Comment: I have edited above ; now someKey/someValue will be like question/search/<id>/<category>/someKey/someValue/...*

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from your urlManager rules in application configuration file. 
Add this bellow line in rules array.

**filePath:** protected/config/main.php

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
         'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<category:([^~,]+)>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ...........
            ...........
```